# Unable to install rbx using rvm on OSX Maverics

Tags: rvm, rubinius

I am getting the below link error while installing rbx-2.2.6 using rvm on OSx Mavrics.
I installed llvm using homebrew.

Can any one please help me out with this?

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, 
std::allocator >&)", referenced from:
      rubinius::JITDisassembler::JITDisassembler(void*, unsigned long)in disassembler.cpp.o
  "llvm::report_fatal_error(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::getPointerToNamedFunction(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, bool)in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::ReleaseRWX(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::JITSlabAllocator::Deallocate(llvm::MemSlab*)      in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::~RubiniusJITMemoryManager()in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::AllocateRWX(unsigned long, llvm::sys::MemoryBlock const*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::allocateNewSlab(unsigned long)in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::setWritable(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusRequestJITMemoryManager::setMemoryWritable()     in jit_context.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::setExecutable(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusRequestJITMemoryManager::setMemoryExecutable()     in jit_context.cpp.o
  "llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass(llvm::raw_ostream&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) const", referenced from:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&)", referenced from:
      rubinius::JITDisassembler::JITDisassembler(void*, unsigned long)in disassembler.cpp.o
  "llvm::report_fatal_error(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::getPointerToNamedFunction(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, bool)in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::ReleaseRWX(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::JITSlabAllocator::Deallocate(llvm::MemSlab*)      in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::~RubiniusJITMemoryManager()in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::AllocateRWX(unsigned long, llvm::sys::MemoryBlock const*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusJITMemoryManager::allocateNewSlab(unsigned long)in jit_memory_manager.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::setWritable(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusRequestJITMemoryManager::setMemoryWritable()     in jit_context.cpp.o
  "llvm::sys::Memory::setExecutable(llvm::sys::MemoryBlock&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
      rubinius::jit::RubiniusRequestJITMemoryManager::setMemoryExecutable()     in jit_context.cpp.o
  "llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass(llvm::raw_ostream&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) const", referenced from:

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to fix the issue. The following post helped in fixing it

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2942#issuecomment-49334237

brew install llvm

rvm install rbx --1.9 -- --skip-system --skip-prebuilt --llvm-path="/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.4"